# How to use http request in https request?

Tags: security, browser

I need run http request in my website with https request.

This code play in my website with http: for example `http://mywebsite.com` but dont play in https: for example `https://mywebsite.com`.

```
<audio id="stream" controls preload="none" autoplay style="width: 400px;">
    <source src="http://185.88.177.45:9948/;" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<script>
    var audio = document.getElementById('stream');
    audio.volume = 0.5;
</script>
```

I use Laravel framwork in Ubuntu Os.

I use `cloudflare` Is there a way?

How to play in https webiste?

Comment: you will need the external source, that youre trying to load, have to run in https aswell.

Comment: This is because you're making a call to an unsecured endpoint (ie. `http://`) from a secure `https://` site. To make this work you need to add an SSL certificate to the domain hosting the currently unsecured content, or move your site to `http://`. The latter is not a good idea, though.

Comment: I guess you could create a HTTPS proxy that itself load the HTTP stream. A browser will now allow unencrypted content, but a separate server isn't bound by any rules.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi, `whmsonic` not support https :(, How to play this code with jquery? or I use `cloudflare`, Is there a way?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes How to create HTTPS proxy? I use `cloudflare`, is there a way?

Comment: @mySun from their site (https://www.whmsonic.com/) it looks like you need to upgrade to SonicPanel

Comment: @mySun Not sure about that. Technically the service can be sitting anywhere, but beware of legal issues, because you are basically retransmitting.